# How to calculate predicted values using an lm.ridge object?

Tags: r, ridge-regression

I've found [this line](http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~jvert/svn/tutorials/practical/linearregression/linearregression.R) of code to calculate predicted values from a ridge.lm model:

```
# Predict is not implemented so we need to do it ourselves
y.pred.ridge = scale(data.test[,1:8],center = F, scale = m.ridge$scales)%*% m.ridge$coef[,which.min(m.ridge$GCV)] + m.ridge$ym
```

Why center is set to FALSE? And why do I need to add the mean of $Y$ to the predicted values?

I thought $X$ values should be scaled before running a ridge regression, which implies the out of samples predictors should be centered and scaled?
And scaling the predictors doesn't imply centering the outcomes of the regression, so why to add the mean of $Y$ to the predictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why center is set to FALSE?

Because of information leakage.  The idea with having a testing dataset is to mimic the situation you would have when using your model to make predictions on totally new data.  Generally, you would not have the chance to center the data your model will see when it is put to use in a production environment.  The correct procedure is to memorize the parameters needed to center the training data, then reuse them on any data you need to make predictions on.  I believe the correct call to scale should be:

```
scale(data.test[,1:8], center = m.ridge$xm, scale = m.ridge$scales)
```

Which uses the fact that the `m.ridge`  automatically centered and scaled its training data, and memorized the needed scaling parameters in `m.ridge$xm` and `m.ridge$scales`.

> And why do I need to add the mean of Y to the predicted values?

Its the intercept term in the ridge regression.  Because the intercept parameter is unpenalized, the intercept term is the mean of the response, just like in regular linear regression.

Comment: I was wondering whether lm.ridge automatically centers and scales. Did you get this information from the code? I checked the MASS book and couldn't find any documentation, not even a mention to lm.ridge().

Comment: Yah, I looked at the code.

Comment: I see, by default the 'Inter' parameter is true, and that triggers centering. When predictors are centered, the intercept coefficient is the average predicted value when all predictors are 0, so Ym must be added. That (wrong) center=F line is very confusing. btw, what kind of scaling is {Xscale <- drop(rep(1/n, n) %*% X^2)^0.5}?

Comment: `(rep(1/n, n) %*% X^2)^.5` is a really clever matrix multiplication to compute the standard deviation of each column.  The result is a 1 by n matrix, and the drop kills the `dim` attribute, making it a vector.  This is then used in the following line `X <- X/rep(Xscale, rep(n, p))` to broadcast divide this standard deviation and standardize the matrix.  Kinda ridiculous : )

Comment: Why would centering conditional on the intercept?

Comment: I don't know, that's confusing to me as well.  My only guess: the programmer is assuming that if you pass a formula with no intercept (which you have to be rather explicit about), it's because you're already centered $X$ **and** $y$ together, and so don't need an intercept.  That's pure speculation though.